# is turning model.train() mode back on necessary after model.eval()?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have this demo code right here:

```py
for epoch in range(0, max_epochs):
    model.train()
    for i, data in enumerate(train_dataloader()):
    #do training stuff
    #validation
    if (validation_condition):
        model.eval()
        #do validation stuff
```

Keep in mind, the validation condition is met at a number of iterations and it happens multiple times per epoch. This is important because then `model.train()` is not called again for some iterations, after `model.eval()` was called.

As I understand, `model.eval()` sets the model in evaluation mode, changing some behaviors, such as excluding dropout layers.

With that in mind, should I call `model.train()` after doing the validation stuff again, so that it "reverts the model to its training state ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a well recognized github with a similar implementation as mine and, indeed, `model.train()` was necessary afterwards